# Какой знак препинания предпочтительнее?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Крупнейший промышленный и культурный центр Астрахань — город, привлекательный для инвесторов и  туристов из России и зарубежья, благодаря участию в программе "Формирование комфортной городской среды" заметно преображается. В этом предложении после слова "зарубежья" что лучше поставить — запятую или тире?

Answer (score 1):

Тире. Здесь дополнение "город, привлекательный для инвесторов и туристов из России и зарубежья" может быть изъято без потери смысла исходного предложения. И при вставке оно выделяется с обеих сторон одинаковыми знаками препинания. Причём пара тире в данном случае предпочтительнее пары запятых, хотя, мне кажется, и пара запятых допустима.

Answer (score 1):

Характеристику города лучше выделить отдельным сообщением и обособить тире:

**Город Астрахань  —  крупнейший промышленный и культурный центр, привлекательный для инвесторов и туристов из России и зарубежья, — благодаря участию в программе "Формирование комфортной городской среды" заметно преображается.**

Пояснение

Заданное предложение сложно для прочтения в интонационном плане.